# how to change the color of multiple div with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have 3 span in a page. With click on them I am showing something. Now I want to change the color of the div which i am selecting.

```
<div class="step_wrapper">
   <div id="step_box1"> <span>Content of page 1</span>
   </div>
   <div id="step_box2"> <span>Content of page 2</span>
   </div>
   <div id="step_box2"> <span>Content of page 3</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to do like

```
 $("step_box1").toggle(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "red");
     }, 
     function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "");
  });

 for 2nd div

$("step_box2").toggle(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "red");
     }, 
     function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "");
  });
```

and for the 3rd one

```
 $("step_box2").toggle(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "red");
     }, 
     function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "");
  });
```

But what i need is to select one at a time and which one is selected that div change color and others are back to normal

Comment: `jQuery.fn.toggle(handler, handler...)` is deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: Try $(this).addClass("your-red-class"); and $(this).removeClass("your-red-class");

Answer (score 5):

You have to set all to normal color before setting one "red", like this:

```
$('.step_wrapper>div').css("background-color", "")
$(this).css("background-color", "red")
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, given the signature of the `toggle()` method you're using I assume that you have included a very old version of jQuery (< 1.9) as that pattern has now been deprecated. You should upgrade jQuery to a newer version in your project.

Secondly, you can achieve this by placing a common event handler on all your div elements, something like this:

```
<div class="step_wrapper">
    <div id="step_box1">
        <span>Content of page 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="step_box2">
        <span>Content of page 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="step_box3">
        <span>Content of page 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".step_wrapper div").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ch3LbL7j/)

Note the use of `addClass()`/`removeClass()`; it's better practice to put styles in an external stylesheet and amend the classnames on elements rather than changing their inline styles directly.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change the background-color of the selected `step_box`, and make the others transparent backgrounds:

```html
<div class="step_wrapper">
   <div id="step_box1"> <span>Content of page 1</span>
   </div>
   <div id="step_box2"> <span>Content of page 2</span>
   </div>
   <div id="step_box2"> <span>Content of page 3</span>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.step_wrapper > div').click(function() {
 $this = $(this);
  
  $this.css('background-color', 'red');
  $this.siblings().css('background-color', 'transparent');
})  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <title>sample Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <style>
        .red {
        background-color:red;
        }

    </style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.step_wrapper div').click(function () {
            $('.step_wrapper div.red').removeClass('red')
            $(this).addClass('red');
        });


    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="step_wrapper">
   <div id="step_box1"> <span>Content of page 1</span>
   </div>
   <div id="step_box2"> <span>Content of page 2</span>
   </div>
   <div id="Div1"> <span>Content of page 3</span>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple CSS Solution**

This can be accomplished with a few lines of CSS.  Note that you must add the tabindex attribute to each DIV to allow it to receive focus. This solution doesn't require any javascript or library.

Run the snippet below and click on the lines of text to see it work.

```css
div:not(:focus) { background-color: none; color: black;}
div:focus { background-color: red; color: white;}
```

```html
<div>
   <div tabindex=1> <span>Content of page 1</span></div>
   <div tabindex=2> <span>Content of page 2</span></div>
   <div tabindex=3> <span>Content of page 3</span></div>
</div>
```